# Monitoring NodeJS API

Tags: node.js

I built a SaaS API in NodeJS (Koa) I would like to implement two types of monitoring. First one is a general monitoring of the API that would include CPU usage, error rates, latency, etc. In the second one I am interested in how many unique visits certain API route had. This will be returned to a user using some other API route.

I have tried swagger-stats which seem to fit my purpose when integrated with elastic search. Are there any other monitoring packages?

Comment: https://swaggerstats.io/ is a good start

Answer (score 0):

i can recommend pm2. it is convinient process manager. then, it support monitoring, and logging you can setup by use 'npm install pm2 -g',
if you want to more information, go to http://pm2.keymetrics.io/.

it is very useful me, i hope that you too!